# Org-capture template with deadline of one month from today

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

As it seems, org-mode capture templates mechanism maybe have changed? I'm using:

Org mode version 9.2.4 (9.2.4-10-g3b006f-elpaplus)

What I'm trying to do is to have a capture template that will create a heading with a DEADLINE, it would prompt for a date, but would use +1m as a default date. So If I do something like this:

```
  ("s" "Someday" entry (file+headline "~/Dropbox/org/tasks.org" "Tasks")
              "* TODO %?\nDEADLINE: %^t\n")
```

This works, but the calendar prompt appears with cursor on Today's date, I want it to be +1m, so if I press `RET` - it will be a month from today. That possible, right?

Answer (score 3):

You can check `org-insert-time-stamp` and `org-read-date`.

```
("s" "Someday" entry (file+headline "~/Dropbox/org/tasks.org" "Tasks")
          "* TODO %?\nDEADLINE: %(org-insert-time-stamp (org-read-date nil t \"+1m\"))\n")
```

Edit: Having the template contain nested %( elements causes each to be evaluated and the result of the inner one is a list, but the engine expects a string or nil